# "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'" when running pitchFX function

Tags: r, sqlite, double, density-plot

I am new to R so please forgive my naivete. I am trying to replicate the code in [this tutorial](http://cpsievert.github.io/pitchRx/RJwrapper.pdf) so I can start doing graphical analysis of baseball data, particularly pitch f/x data. The code I am trying to replicate is at the end of page 8.

I have a sqlite database (GamedayDB.sqlite3) that has five tables. The two being utilized in the following code are pitch and atbat.

I am attempting to merge the two tables using the "gameday_link" and "num" fields. I would like to see a density plot showing the locations of the called strikes by left and right-handed batters.

```
library(dplyr)

abt <- data.frame(
    gameday_link = c("gid_2017_05_01_tormlb_nyamlb_1"),
    num =   c("1","5","36","18","4","29","3","2","15","7"),
    b_height    =   c(6-0,6-4,6-0,6-0,6-1,5-10,5-10,6-0,5-10,5-9),
    p_throws    =   c(L),
    stand   =   c(R,R,R,R,R,R,R,L,L,L),
    inning_side =   c(top)
)

pt <- data.frame(
    gameday_link    =   c("gid_2017_05_01_tormlb_nyamlb_1"),    
    num =   c("1","1","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3"), 
    px  =   c(NA,NA,-1.53727726,-1.26172472,-0.24361091,-1.24640143,0.60803018,0.03911084,1.93196081,1.21868256),   
    pz  =   c(NA,NA,2.587125,2.351845,2.460072,1.611097,2.6777,3.020731,1.721488,1.344171), 
    des = c("Called","In","Ball","Called","Called","Ball","In","Called","Called","Ball")
)

dt <- collect(inner_join(pt, abt, by = c('gameday_link','num')))
dt$strike <- as.numeric(dt$des %in% "Called")

relabel <- function(variable, value) {
    value <- sub("^R$","Right-Handed Batter", value)
    sub("^L$","Left-Handed Batter", value)
}

library(pitchRx)

strnc <- subset(dt, select = c("px","pz","b_height","p_throws","stand",
                                 "inning_side","des","strike"))
st <- subset(strnc, strike == 1)
rm(strnc)

strikeFX(st, geom = "tile", density1 = list(des = "Called"),
     density2 = list(des = "Called")) + facet_grid(. ~ stand, labeller = 
relabel)
```

Comment: Can you make your code reproducible (incl. data) and only include the absolute necessary part(s)?

Comment: I uploaded a truncated version of the GamedayDB.sqlite3 database called "GamedayDB_test.sqlite3" to dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxxh2hpni67eyhn/GamedayDB_test.sqlite3?dl=0

It's still pretty large at 30 MBs. I updated the code with the database name changed to the test version

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to provide a minimal reproducible example. Try making it as general as possible.

Comment: I attempted to recreate the error and the script above works like I was hoping the original would. I'm not sure how to recreate the error but I believe the error it has something to do with this section of the original code, specifically the "decisions" inner_join:
decisions <- collect(inner_join(pitch, atbat, by = c('gameday_link','num')))

Comment: Is it possible when I import data from sqlite through the following script, I can import it as unformatted data?
pt <- select(tbl(my_db,"pitch"), gameday_link, num, px, pz, des)